# How do I pass the value of a primary to the foreign key and then use it to display information from the database?

Tags: laravel, controller

I want the contacts to be displayed specifically according to the group. The groups in turn are being displayed according to the logged in user. However, all the contacts for the user are being displayed in every group that the user creates.It works when the value is being hardcoded but I want the value to be assigned dynamically.How do I do that?

This is the group controller

```
class GroupController extends Controller {
public function index()
{
    $groups = Group::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
    return view('groups.index', compact('groups'));
}
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $group = $request->all();
  $request->validate([
    'group_name'=>'required',
  ]);
  $group = new Group([
    'group_name' => $request->get('group_name'),
    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
  ]);
  $group->save();
  return redirect('/groups');
 }}
```

This is the contact controller

```
class ContactController extends Controller{
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $group_id=$request->query('id');
    $contacts = Contact::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->where('group_id','=','id')->get();
    return view('contacts.index', compact('contacts'));
}
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $contact = $request->all(); 
  $request->validate([
    'contact_name'=>'required',
    'contact_number'=> 'required|integer',
    'contact_email' => 'required'
  ]);
  $contact = new Contact([
    'contact_name' => $request->get('contact_name'),
    'contact_number'=> $request->get('contact_number'),
    'contact_email'=> $request->get('contact_email'),
    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
    'group_id'=> $request->query('id'),
  ]);
  $contact->save();
  return redirect('/contacts');
}}
```

This is the migration for contacts.

```
class CreateContactsTable extends Migration{
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('contact_name');
        //$table->string('contact_number');
        $table->string('contact_email');
        $table->string('contact_number')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('contacts', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('group_id')->references('id')->on('groups');
    });}
```

Comment: you can easily achieve this by using eloquent relationship
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I have used these relationships in the models. It is still not working. public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(App\User, 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(App\Contact, 'group_id')->withTimestamps();
    }